# Is there a way to automatically change SMTP server?

Tags: email, settings

I have a friend with a ntlworld.com email address. For desktop setup the SMTP server is smtp.ntlworld.com, but this only accepts email from IP addresses served by Virgin Media (who bought NTL) as ISP. When on 3G, they can use the SMTP server of their network provider.

So is there a way to have one SMTP server for WiFi and another SMTP server when not on WiFi?

Answer (score 1):

Basically I had the same problem, and if you had an iphone **spits on ground** I would say yes (you can set more than one smtp server up and if it fails on one it'll try on the other) . . you can just get round it by turning off the phones wifi when you want to send an email (at home)

Emails can be sent over the phone network using their smtp server (smtp.orange.net for example) but as soon as you hit your home network (via wifi) the  orange out-going server will not work (because it doesn't know  who you are because you are going through your own ISP), where as if you change your smtp server back to ntlworld it would work (because you are using your home connection)(hope that made sence?)

O2 solved this issue, because they had a user name and password for their smtp server, so even if you sent an email over wifi (at home) it could authenticate who you were and subsequently send it.

I tried explaining this to orange . . .  it fell on deaf ears

Answer (score 1):

They support authentication to use the mail server to send email - particularly since these days the service is run by Google.  [This page](http://help.virginmedia.com/system/selfservice.controller?CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=3638&CURRENT_CMD=SEARCH&CONFIGURATION=1002&PARTITION_ID=1&USERTYPE=1&LANGUAGE=en&COUNTY=us&VM_CUSTOMER_TYPE=Cable) covers the settings in detail, but the key points are:

1. Configure it to use authentication
2. Configure it to use SSL
3. Configure it to use port 465 for SMTP if selecting SSL didn't change it already

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of apps that allow you to program-without-programming to set up conditions on your phone that trigger changes in settings and such. **[Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tasker/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** is one a friend at work uses, and I know there was at least one other (though I can't remember the name right now). I've never used them personally, so I don't know exactly what trigger conditions they have (such as switching from a specific wifi network to another data connection). You may want to check those out though and see if they meet your needs. Oh, another is **[Locale](http://www.appbrain.com/app/locale/com.twofortyfouram.locale)**, which looks (according to appbrain) to have a lot of plugins developed for it to add additional triggers and actions... you may even be able to get a plugin written for it to do what you want if there isn't one.